# Debug.DrawRay makes player velocity very high

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm having this problem where my Game object(player) velocity increases a lot becouse of Debug.DrawRay, this makes no sense, and i don't know what to do.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using static Unity.Collections.AllocatorManager;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed;
    public float JumpForce;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public bool OnGround;
    public bool Jump;
    public bool MobileJump;

    private bool MoveLeftBool;
    private bool MoveRightBool;

    public LayerMask Blocks;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        OnGround = false;

        MoveLeftBool = false;
        MoveRightBool = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //The Problem
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position -= new Vector3(5, 0, 0), -transform.up, Color.green, 1);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Jump = false;
        }

        if(Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position -= new Vector3(-5, 0, 0), -transform.up, 1, Blocks))
        {
            OnGround = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OnGround = false;
        }
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position -= new Vector3(5, 0, 0), -transform.up, 1, Blocks))
        {
            OnGround = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OnGround = false;
        }
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, 1, Blocks))
        {
            OnGround = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OnGround = false;
        }
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        MoveLeftBool = true;
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {
        MoveRightBool = true;
    }

    public void StopMoving()
    {
        MoveLeftBool = false;
        MoveRightBool = false;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    public void JumpMethod()
    {
        MobileJump = true;
    }
    public void StopJumpMethod()
    {
        MobileJump = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Jump && OnGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0);
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce * 10));
            Jump = false;
        }
        if (MobileJump && OnGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0);
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce * 10));
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || MoveLeftBool)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-Speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || MoveRightBool)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(Speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }

    //On Ground Collision Detection
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Spike"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

i tried to delete the line of code, and it worked the player stopped acting weird, but i need that line for debugging and i want to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is this line modifies transform.position

`Debug.DrawRay(transform.position -= new Vector3(5, 0, 0), -transform.up, Color.green, 1);`

Even though it's in a method, -= reassigns the variable's position. Remove the -=, and the problem should go away.

`Debug.DrawRay(transform.position - new Vector3(5, 0, 0), -transform.up, Color.green, 1);`

Comment: oh right, wow thank you so much. i was tryning to understand the problem from a long time, you made my day.